# How do I make a JButton with an anonymous innerclass actionlistener remove itself on click?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

Hello and thanks for reading this in advance, here is my problem:

```
final JButton button = new JButton();

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionevent)
            {
                button.setVisible(false);
                button.validate();
                button.invalidate();
                button.revalidate();
                button.repaint();
            }
        });
```

I have tried all those to just make that button go away, I have disabled it aswell, but I need it to just go away, not fade out or something. the background is variabel so I can't make it so it has the same color as it and pretend it's not there. Does anyone have any clue at all how to make it go away?

**EDIT**: I've tried all answers uptill now and would really like to thank you, but the button's still there :(

**EDIT2**: I think I've made quite a big mistake constantly adding buttons because of my timer, thanks for all the help, this still was very usefull!

**EDIT3**: Thank you all very much, I have fixed the problem with your guys' help :)

Comment: Remember when you called addComponent(button)... you need a matching remove at that level.

Comment: You don't revalidate and repaint the *button* but rather its *container*!

Comment: My guess is that you have a layout problem, and you probably have two buttons stacked one above the other or something like that. setVisible(false) is sufficient to hide a button. I just tested it: https://gist.github.com/jnizet/4726452. Post an SSCCE (just like I did) to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to remove the button:

```
Container parent = button.getParent();
parent.remove(button);
((JComponent) parent).revalidate();
parent.repaint();
```

if you want to remove action listener from the button:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionevent)
{
  button.removeActionListener(this);
}
```

Comment: This worked after I fixed another part of my code, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need it after you 'dispose' of it, feel free to remove it from the parent.

`button.getParent().remove(button);`

Else, follow HoverCraftFullOfEel's advice.

Comment: He still needs to call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on the Component's parent Container after removing the Component.